# Spellcheck in Firefox doesn’t work on full page

Tags: firefox, spell-check

The speller check doesn’t work in full page. When a page is very big the check speller only works a little.

Like [in this page of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia&action=edit)

[image]

How I can fix this?

Comment: The solution

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1094294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a maximum number of errors that are flagged.

- extensions.spellcheck.inline.max-misspellings = 500

You may be hitting this limit on a big page with a lot of errors.

You can open the about:config page via the location/address bar.
You can accept the warning and click "I'll be careful" to continue.

- http://kb.mozillazine.org/about:config

The solution [The solution](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1094294)